# Appium not recognising the elements

Tags: selenium, appium

I am experiencing a weird problem in object identification. I have 3 fields username, password and login buttons. The username field is recognised and I am able to key in the data. But Appium is not recognising the other 2 fields no matter what. I need help.

[image]

```
public class LoginPageObjects {

    @AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiSelector().text(\" Employee ID or Email\")")
    private AndroidElement username;

    @AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiSelector().text(\"Password\")" )
    private AndroidElement password;

    @AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiSelector().text(\"LOGIN\")")
    private AndroidElement loginsubmit;

    public AndroidElement getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public AndroidElement getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public AndroidElement getLoginsubmit() {
        return loginsubmit;
    }
}
```

public class LoginPageFuncs extends LoginPageObjects {

```
private AndroidDriver driver;

public LoginPageFuncs(AndroidDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
}

public void doLogin(Map<String, String> table) throws InterruptedException {
    getUsername().sendKeys(table.get("username"));
    getPassword().sendKeys(table.get("password"));
    getLoginsubmit().click();
}
```

}

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.13.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of spaces with text you are trying to get.

Try this:

```java
public class LoginPageObjects {

    @AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiSelector().textContains(\" Employee ID or Email\")")
    private AndroidElement username;

    @AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiSelector().textContains(\"Password\")" )
    private AndroidElement password;

    @AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiSelector().textContains(\"LOGIN\")")
    private AndroidElement loginsubmit;

    public AndroidElement getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public AndroidElement getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public AndroidElement getLoginsubmit() {
        return loginsubmit;
    }
}
```